# Inequality involving three functions

Tags: inequalities

I have the follwing inequality, which I am not sure if it is correct or not.
$$\int_{0}^{h} \int_{0}^{h} \max(u,v) f(u) f(v) du dv \geq \int_{0}^{h} \int_{0}^{h} \min(u,v) du dv \int_{0}^{h}\int_{0}^{h} f(u)f(v) du dv, $$  where $f$ is an $L^2$ function , $f$ is the a.e derivative of $F$, and $F$ is also in $L^2$, $0 \leq u, v \leq h $

The final thing that I am trying to prove is the following:
$$\int_{0}^{h} \int_{0}^{h} \max(u,v) f(u) f(v) du dv \geq \int_{0}^{h} \int_{0}^{h} \min(u,v) du dv \int_{0}^{h} f^2 du .$$

Comment: I guess you mean $0\le u,v\le h$

Comment: right, you are correct here

Comment: You certainly are in trouble if $f$ is concentrated near $0$, say $f=1$ on $[0,\delta]$ and $0$ on $(\delta,h]$ with $\delta\ll h$.

Comment: The question is unclearly formulated. In particular, could $h$ be $\infty$?

Comment: No h is finite. I am pasting a link to the place from where the basic problem has arisen. https://statistics.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/EFS%20NSF%20159.pdf. On pg 9 of this the authors are trying to prove that $ \frac{1}{h^2}\int_0^h (f -f_h)^2  - \frac{1}{12} \int_{0}^{h}f^{'}^{2}$ can be small. The $1/12$ fraction only comes if we are able to get some kind of inequality as above. Since the author has not explicity mentioned hence I was trying to derive it. The $1/12 $ fraction appears to be coming from the min value that the expression can have.

Comment: Thank you. Don't you miss condition (1.4) from the manuscript in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your inequalities are false in general, in view of homogeneity considerations. Indeed, note first that
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^h\int_0^h \min(u,v) du dv=\int_0^h dv\int_0^v du\, u+\int_0^h du\int_0^u dv\, v=\frac{h^3}3.
\end{equation}
Let now $f=1$ on $[0,h]$. Then the left side of your displayed inequalities is 
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^h\int_0^h \max(u,v) f(u) f(v)\, du\, dv
 \le\int_0^h\int_0^h h \, du\, dv=h^3, 
\end{equation}
whereas their right sides are, respectively, $\frac{h^3}3\,h^2$ and $\frac{h^3}3\,h$, which are greater than $h^3$ if $h>3$.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate your answer? In particular, why "Then the left side of your displayed inequalities is $\leq h^3$"?

Comment: I have provided details.

Comment: I woud state this simpler: if $f$ is dimensionless, and $u,v,h$ are measured in feet, then the left hand side has dimension $ft^3$ while the RHS  has $ft^5$ and  $ft^4$. And we have the same inconsistency whatever the dimension of $f$ is.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : This is how I was actually thinking (except that it was centimeters rather than feet :-); I certainly prefer the simple and natural Gauss metric unit CGS system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units) to any other), and this is what I meant by the "homogeneity considerations".

Comment: @IosifPinelis: when I studied in high school (in mid 1970s) we were taught that CGS is out of date, and replaced with SI system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : I know that, and I think it is a great pity. Instead of the simple and natural formula $F=q_1q_2/r^2$ in CGS for the Coulomb law, in SI they have this terrible extra factor $1/(4\pi\epsilon_0)$. Instead of only three basic CGS units, in SI they have 7 basic units (if my count is correct), including (yes) the **basic unit** candela; and then they have about 3 million derived SI units, mostly named after persons. Looks quite crazy to me! When I was in high school (late 60s), we only had to deal with CGS, thankfully.

Answer (score 0):

Both your inequalities are wrong, because the LHS can be negative.
Indeed, take $h=3,\; f(x)=\delta(x-1)-\delta(x-2)$ then the left hand side will
be $-1$. Now approximate the deltas with smooth functions.

On the other hand, in your second inequalty (the final thing) the right hand side
is always non-negative, while in the first inequality it is zero for the example above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate your answer, giving us details?